# How to load a model like three.js editor？

Tags: javascript, three.js

I noticed that when I import a model into Three.js Editor,It didin't upload the model to remote server.It seems copying the model to Browser Cache（I disconnected my network and it works fine）.I want to know how to do like this，and is there any demo for me to learn.
Anyone help me？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript can read local files via the [File API](https://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/).
No need to upload it to the server.
You can see how the three.js editor does it by looking in the repository.
Specifically, the [Loader.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/editor/js/Loader.js) file I think.
You can find plenty of examples of using the file api on the interwebs.
**[Here is an example](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)**, but there are plenty more.

Comment: Thank you. I try it and load an image into Browser successfully.But when I try to replace path of my model in OBJloader.load, I failed.I read loader.js but don't competely know how it works .I want to load the model into my scene,is there any way to do it?

Comment: You can simply load the text from your file and call the [OBJLoader.parse(text)](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js#L421) function on it. No need to use the OBJLoader.load function (which I assume does not handle local files).

Comment: I try this method yesterday,but I think an other problem occurs to me……when I use  OBJLoader.parse(fileobject) ,console says:text.indexOf is not a function.I think I need more time to learn it .Thanks again.

Comment: Did you create a `FileReader` object and call something like `var fileText = filereader.readAsText(fileobject); OBJLoader.parse(fileText);` ? I have not done it but am going by the documentation I have found. In the example I posted, read the part about "Reading files"

Comment: Yes,I succeed now.And now what troubles me is how to give a texture map to my model loaded in scene……

Comment: There are many examples on the interwebs about that. I have some examples on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user/2pha/fiddles/) though my fiddle examples use a dataurl instead of a file path

Comment: Thank you.I means that I don't know how to create a material for my model.I only know how to create material with loader.load().

Comment: `var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );`. Please do your own research, there are a million and 1 examples of this on the interwebs.